# Why does jQuery show() cause a brief but noticeable jerk when unhiding a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a hidden div on a form the first time that a user clicks the submit button. Whilst I have this working using jQuery, if I set any value other than 0 for the show() transition period, the div that is being show "jerks" to the side.

This is using Bootstrap and tested on Safari.

I think the problem may be around `margin: 0 auto` on the form (it's as if the margins align after jQuery has shown the element).

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqq8x/1/) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of jQuery's animation wrappers.  jQuery puts an element that is about to be animated in another `div` helper for the animation.

This wrapper messes up margins on the element being animated (almost) every time.

I changed this rule:

```
#signup-form .form-group {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

To this:

```
#signup-form .form-group {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

removing the top margin.

The jQuery animation adds a wrapper around the element which kills the top margin while the animation is underway.  As soon as the animation is over jQuery unwraps the element, and the margin is applied, creating the jump.

Here is an **[updated JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cqq8x/3/)**.

Answer (score 1):

you execute css twice, for that reason the "jerk" occurs

change to the following:

```
#signup-form {
margin: 10px auto;
}

#signup-form-submit {
width: 200px;
margin: 10px auto;
}
```

here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cqq8x/4/

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because of the addition of the scrollbar when the new div makes the page too long. This adjusts the width of the page, which does change the alignment as you noted.

Sorry, this only happens on smaller screens. I'm updating with an answer for bigger screens.

Update: It appears the order of functions also impacts things. I moved

```
$('#signup-form-submit').removeClass('show-hidden-div');
```

above the show function and it is much cleaner.

Comment: Is there a workaround? `.show(400)` looks a lot nicer than `.show(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I got is working by removing this line in the css

```
#signup-form .form-group {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

at least that is a start

Answer (score 0):

Jerking happens when the **parent div ".collapse"** has padding.

Padding goes on the child div, not the parent. jQuery is animating the height, not the padding.

Example:

```
  <div id="collapseForm" class="container collapse in">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 pd">
           Padding goes on the child div. Not the parent.
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.